# Creating a fake or dummy pid in elixir

Tags: process, pid, elixir

In erlang it is possible to create a pid which does not correspond to a process. An example using this can be found [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/more-on-multiprocessing#time-out) in Learn You Some Erlang.

```
pid(0,250,0).
```

Is there a way to do the same in elixir?
The closes I have got at the moment is to create a process that immediately terminates and use that pid.

```
fake_pid = Process.spawn(fn -> end)
```

This seams like a bit of a hack, and I am unsure if there might be some slight differences between a never created pid and a dead pid.

Comment: The problem with creating a fake pid is that you can't know for sure that it doesn't refer to an actual process. You might create one, then immediately check to see if any process identified by that pid is alive, but even if there isn't one at that instant, one might spring into existence later that does have that pid. Why do you need a fake pid? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am testing a function that takes a pid as one argument. For certain combinations of the other arguments the pid is not used. so I only need a pid to pass the guard checks but doesnt need to reference anything

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [pid/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/c.html#pid-3) Erlang function [directly in Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#calling-functions):

```
:c.pid(0,250,0)
```

Also - just a note from the Erlang docs:

> Converts X, Y, Z to the pid <X.Y.Z>. This function should only be used when debugging.

Comment: what is that `:c` module?

Comment: From the Erlang docs: "The c module enables users to enter the short form of some commonly used commands."

Answer (score 9):

For your purposes, I would use `self()` from the test code. That would resolve to the process running the current test case.

If you for some reason need to test another pid, your way of using `Process.spawn/1` is quite nice, because it ensures the pid is not taken (and doesn't point to something vital in the system) and that it is already dead (or alive, if you keep it alive for the duration of the test).

The Erlang `:c.pid/3` or the new Elixir 1.1 `IEx.Helpers.pid/3` are only meant to be convenience functions to be used in the shell.